Logs are not available in Splunk after Java 17 upgrade
I am trying to upgrade mule application to Java 17 and runtime 4.6 (LTS). We have Splunk configured and it is observed that after the upgrade the logs are not going to Splunk.
Did anyone faced this issue and how to resolve this issue?
TIA
